# MySQL / Classic ASP - Parameterized Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, asp-classic

In an absolute emergency, I am trying to go through my website and add parameterized queries. I'm a newbie and have only just learnt about them.

My problem is, I only know a very little about connection types and all of the examples I'm seeing are using another methods of connection, which is confusing me. I don't particularly want to change the way I connect to my DB, as it's on lots of pages, I just want to update my queries to be safer.

This is how I have been connecting to my DB:

```
Set connContent = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
connContent.ConnectionString = "...blah...blah...blah..."
connContent.Open
```

and this is the SQL bit with parameters:

```
username = Trim(Request("username"))
connContent.Prepared = True

Const ad_nVarChar = 202
Const ad_ParamInput = 1

SQL = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username=?) ; "

Set newParameter = connContent.CreateParameter("@username", ad_nVarChar, adParamInput, 20, username)
connContent.Parameters.Append newParameter

Set rs = connContent.Execute(SQL)

If NOT rs.EOF Then
        ' Do something...
End If

rs.Close
```

It's obviously not working but I need to know if I can actually achieve this using the connection I have or am I missing something altogether that's stopping it from working?

Before I go forth and spend the next 2 days debugging something I'm unfamiliar with, I would like to know I'm at least on the right track...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your second snippet is correct, but should be applied to a new `ADODB.Command` object, not to the `Connection` object:

```vb
username = Trim(Request("username"))

'-----Added this-----
Dim cmdContent
Set cmdContent = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

' Use this line to associate the Command with your previously opened connection
Set cmdContent.ActiveConnection = connContent
'--------------------

cmdContent.Prepared = True

Const ad_nVarChar = 202
Const ad_ParamInput = 1

SQL = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username=?) ; "

Set newParameter = cmdContent.CreateParameter("@username", ad_nVarChar, ad_ParamInput, 20, username)
cmdContent.Parameters.Append newParameter

cmdContent.CommandText = SQL
Set rs = cmdContent.Execute

If NOT rs.EOF Then
        ' Do something...
End If

rs.Close
```

By the way, there was a typo with the spelling of `adParamInput` instead of `ad_ParamInput` (corrected in my example).

Comment: This is great thanks. I really, really appreciate it. One question, any ideas why I would get the error "SQL data type out of range"?

Comment: Best to ask that as a new question.

Comment: Okay, I noticed that MySQL does not like (ad_nVarChar=202), so I changed it to (ad_varChar=200) and it worked. Thanks again..